# How to add multiple attribute - vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

This works:

```
<input v-model="project.name" :readonly="isReadOnly" :disabled="isReadOnly">
```

Is there a way to make below code work?

```
<input v-model="project.name" {{ readOnlyAttr }} >
<input v-model="project.name" {{ isReadOnly : 'readonly disabled' ? ''}}>
```

Script as follows:

```
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      isReadOnly: {
        default: ture,
        type: Boolean
      }
    },
    data () {
      return {
        readOnlyAttr: 'readonly disabled'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: not sure i understood - u want to group toghter all the attributes in a single object to pass?

Comment: @LiranC yes, as simple as that, just group the attributes and apply to the element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`v-bind` is your friend here.
Because you want the attributes to be computed, I created a computed method to build the object everytime there is a change to `isReadOnly` value.

When you want to bind statically group of attributes, you can use the `data` method.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="project.name" v-bind="readOnlyAttributes">
  </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  name: 'example',
  computed: {
    readOnlyAttributes() {
      return {
        readonly: this.isReadOnly,
        disabled: this.isReadOnly ? 'readonly' : ''
      }
    },
    isReadOnly() {
      // returning always true for the example
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help :) Here is what I did:
This is how I call the form:
`<base-form :project="project" :is-read-only="true"></base-form>`
Here is my template:
`<input v-model="project.name" v-bind="readOnlyAttributes">
<input v-model="project.place" v-bind="readOnlyAttributes">`
The script looks like this now as you suggested, It's works :)
`props: { isReadOnly: { default: false, type: Boolean } },
computed: { readOnlyAttributes () { return { readonly: this.isReadOnly, disabled: this.isReadOnly } } }`